# Custom live chat script not working in Magento 2.2.4

Tags: magento2, knockoutjs, requirejs

I have tried adding the chat script on `.phtml` of the custom extension which I have created for integrating my own live chat. But the libraries are showing undefined when the chat plugin loads the `minified js`.
Please let me know if there is any specific way to define libraries in **Magento 2** which are being used in **chat js** as the same plugin is working on other platforms.

```
<script type = "text/javascript" >
   function initSupportScript() {
       var t = document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0],
           e = document.createElement("script");
       e.type = "text/javascript", e.src = 'https://www.example.com/plugins/js/chatcustomersupport.v3.min.js', e.onload = initChat, t.appendChild(e)
   }
if ("undefined" == typeof jQuery) {
   var headTag = document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0],
       jqTag = document.createElement("script");
   jqTag.type = "text/javascript", jqTag.src = "https://www.example.com/static/assets/global/plugins/jquery.min.js", jqTag.onload = initSupportScript, headTag.appendChild(jqTag)
} else initSupportScript();

/* Initialize Chat */
function initChat() {
   Chat.initialize({
       customercode: 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx', // encrypted customer code 
       key: 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx', // partner support key
       iv: 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx', // pseudo random string in hex format
       label: 'Live Support',
       context: 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx',
       success: function() {
           // your callback here (optional)
       },
       error: function(e) {
           console.log(e);
       }
   });
}
</script>
```

thanks

Comment: Can you add your error here ?

Comment: error in console -
"TypeError: timesync is undefined" - |
but timesync minified version is already added in chat js

Answer (score 1):

You can refer extension for crisp chate here: https://github.com/magepow/magento-2-crisp-chat